# How does operator precedence work for conditional blocks?

Tags: ruby

Why is it that if I call a conditional method without a block, I can do `if foo? bar.baz`, but with a block I have to do:

```
if foo?; bar.each { |n| n.baz } end
```

And how would I do the same with a multi-line block?

```
bar.each do |n|
  n.quack
end
```

Comment: All these ifs are very difficult to read. Extract result of `bar.each` into a variable and - bam! - problem eliminated. Also, `#each` does not what you might think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use and these constructions but how mentioned above it's not readable. You have to avoid writing unreadable code.

```
if true then [1, 2].map { |n| n * 2 } end
=> [2, 4] 

[1, 2].map do |n|
  n * 2
end if true
=> [2, 4] 

[1, 2].map do |n|
  n * 2
end if false
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

The first version you provide will pass the result from bar.each execution to foo? so it expects foo? to take an argument.

Second version will do `bar.each` only if `foo?` is true.

I would advice you to use the following style:

```
if foo?
   bar.each do |n|
     n.quack
   end 
end
```

Which also answers your last question.

NOTE: if you actually expect to pass a single argument to `foo?` that is the result of the execution of the block, you better use a helper variable:

```
cond = bar.each do |n|
  n.quack
end 

if foo? cond
   .. do stuff
end
```

Comment: The result of `each` is to pass back `bar` as the result, so `cond` isn't needed, `if foo? bar` is equivalent - as long as the block exerts no side effects on `bar` (which would be a bad idea anyway).

Comment: @lain I said `you better` not `you should` of course you may decide not to use a variable but this will not help your design nor the readability at all

Comment: Adding variables that don't really do anything is bad practice, as is implying that `each` is equivalent (in practice) to a function like `map`.